# How can I fail the build on warnings?

Tags: swagger-codegen

I have the following configuration :

```
  <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.23</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-models</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <modelPackage>com.models</modelPackage>
                            <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                        <arg>-Werror</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And in my swagger I purposely referenced an invalid value called `"New type"`

My goal is to fail the build when this situation happens (or any error or warning actually) but  I only see a warning and my build continues as usual.

`[WARNING] no property from New type`

Answer (score 0):

Swagger Codegen maven plugin doesn't support build failure on warnings.

You may instead validate the OpenAPI input using https://apitools.dev/swagger-cli/ before passing it to the maven plugin.